# Features and libraries of Nexus 5

Tags: android, nexus-5

I need a list of libraries and features that are installed/available on a Nexus 5 for my Play Store client (http://app-download.org). Since I don't possess a Nexus 5 it would be really helpful if someone could just open a shell on a Nexus 5 device (preferable a vanilla device) with adb and post the output of `pm list libraries` and `pm list features`. I already searched the internet for that data but couldn't find it. This would be of great help to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**pm list libraries**

```
library:android.test.runner
library:com.android.future.usb.accessory
library:com.android.lge.lgsvcitems
library:com.android.location.provider
library:com.android.media.remotedisplay
library:com.google.android.ble
library:com.google.android.camera2
library:com.google.android.maps
library:com.google.android.media.effects
library:com.google.widevine.software.drm
library:com.qualcomm.qcrilhook
library:javax.obex
```

**pm list features**

```
feature:reqGlEsVersion=0x30000
feature:android.hardware.audio.low_latency
feature:android.hardware.bluetooth
feature:android.hardware.bluetooth_le
feature:android.hardware.camera
feature:android.hardware.camera.any
feature:android.hardware.camera.autofocus
feature:android.hardware.camera.flash
feature:android.hardware.camera.front
feature:android.hardware.faketouch
feature:android.hardware.location
feature:android.hardware.location.gps
feature:android.hardware.location.network
feature:android.hardware.microphone
feature:android.hardware.nfc
feature:android.hardware.nfc.hce
feature:android.hardware.screen.landscape
feature:android.hardware.screen.portrait
feature:android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer
feature:android.hardware.sensor.barometer
feature:android.hardware.sensor.compass
feature:android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope
feature:android.hardware.sensor.light
feature:android.hardware.sensor.proximity
feature:android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter
feature:android.hardware.sensor.stepdetector
feature:android.hardware.telephony
feature:android.hardware.telephony.cdma
feature:android.hardware.telephony.gsm
feature:android.hardware.touchscreen
feature:android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch
feature:android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct
feature:android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.jazzhand
feature:android.hardware.usb.accessory
feature:android.hardware.usb.host
feature:android.hardware.wifi
feature:android.hardware.wifi.direct
feature:android.software.app_widgets
feature:android.software.backup
feature:android.software.device_admin
feature:android.software.home_screen
feature:android.software.input_methods
feature:android.software.live_wallpaper
feature:android.software.managed_profiles
feature:android.software.print
feature:android.software.sip
feature:android.software.sip.voip
feature:android.software.voice_recognizers
feature:android.software.webview
feature:com.google.android.feature.EXCHANGE_6_2
feature:com.google.android.feature.GOOGLE_BUILD
feature:com.google.android.feature.GOOGLE_EXPERIENCE
```